# Solve for coefficients of $y = A(1 - e^{-x/B})$ given two points

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

I have the equation $y = A(1 - e^{-x/B})$, and two $(x,y)$ pairs. How can I solve for $A$ and $B$? This should be simple, but I've been banging my head against the algebra for a while to no avail.

I should probably mention that this is not homework.

Comment: Do you have particular values for the pairs, or are they arbitrary?

Comment: Consider $$\frac{y_1}{y_2}=\frac{1-e^{-\frac {x_1}B}}{1-e^{-\frac {x_2}B}}$$ and how one might manipulate it around to isolate $B$

Comment: Also note [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/241433/find-expotential-function-from-two-points)

Answer (score 0):

If you have two particular points, $(x_1, y_1)$, and $(x_2, y_2)$, then you have two equations and two unknowns: $$A=\frac{y_1}{1-e^{-x_1/B}}$$ $$B=-x_2\left(\ln\left(\frac{y_2-A}{-A}\right)\right)^{-1}$$
Since $x_1$, $y_1$, $x_2$, and $y_2$ are constants, this is like solving an a regular two equation to unknown algebra problem, albeit a nasty one.

Comment: I was able to get something like that, but I couldn't figure out how to proceed. Unfortunately my notes are at work, so I can't recall exactly how far I got.

Comment: I would probably plug in what we have for $B$ in the first equation  with $A$. That way we get some potential cancellations with the $e$ and the $ln$... Also remember all the exponent rules! Good luck!

Comment: I just end up with $A = \frac{y_1}{1-(\frac{y_2-A}{-A})^{x_1/x_2}}$